# Static Files Are Not Visible in AKS deployment of Defectdojo

Tags: python, deployment

We tried deploying DefectDojo to our AKS cluster. But the static files (js, css, images) are not downloaded when opening the website.

But when running a local instance of the app in Ubuntu VM, the site runs correctly.

How can I make this python app to download the static files?